# Using the factor function to assign labels

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I'm new to R. I was hoping for some guidance on my hw question.
I'm trying to assign labels up and down to a variable. The code is running but I keep getting NA as values.
Here is my code:

```r
NewVar <- if_else(data1$NewVar>median(data1$NewVar, na.rm = TRUE),"1","0")
factor(NewVar)
factor(NewVar, levels=c("up","down"))
```

output:

```r
  [1] 0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1   
 [30] 0    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1   
 [59] 1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    1   
 [88] 0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0   
[117] 0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    NA 0    0    0   

Levels: 0 1

  [1] NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [30] NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [59] NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [88] NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[117] NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: high low
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Notice the difference between `levels=` here and @Ben's use of `labels=`. From `?factor`, levels is *"an optional vector of the unique values ... that 'x' might have taken"*, but `"up"` and `"down"` are not observed in your vector of `"1"`/`"0"`. If you change your code to use `labels=` instead, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a minute to check this: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) post out. It will help you ask more questions regarding `R`.

what you'll want, is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(4211)
old <- c(rnorm(100), NA)

NewVar <- if_else(old>median(old, na.rm = TRUE),"1","0")
factor(NewVar, labels=c("up","down"))
```

```
  [1] up   up   down down down up   down down down up   up   down down up   down up  
 [17] up   up   up   up   down down down down down up   up   down up   down up   down
 [33] up   down down down up   up   up   down up   up   up   down up   down up   down
 [49] down up   up   up   down down down down down up   down up   down down down up  
 [65] down up   up   up   down up   down down down down down down up   up   down up  
 [81] up   up   up   down up   up   up   up   up   up   down down up   down up   up  
 [97] up   down down down <NA>
Levels: up down
```

In this example, `old` is just some vector, much like your `data$NewVar` variable. What you are doing wrong in your code is that you are calling `factor()` twice. Moreover, you want to set the labels, not the levels. Moreover, you might also want to include the `levels` parameter, to specify which of the 1, 0s is corresponding to which label. To do so, just add `levels=c("0","1")` or `levels=c("1", "0")` to your function call, depending on whether "0" stands for up or down. It probably stands for down, so `levels=c("1", "0")` would be the way to go.

Comment: In that same example for making a great R reproducible example, it suggested the use of `set.seed` *in the case of random processes* :-)

Comment: I see. Yeah i changed levels and it worked. thank you